# JQuery-Steps Wizard only show Step1 upon page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I'm using Jquery-Steps wizard. Currently when the page loads there is a brief delay whereby all the wizard steps display unstyled until the javascript and css kicks in. It looks terrible and negates the wizard effect.

Is there a way to only display the wizard step 1 upon page load without briefly displaying all the other hidden wizard steps?

Thank you!

Comment: Show some code or a demo, please. As this doesn't happen on the example pages (http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form), we'll need something more to go on.

Comment: can you style them with css `display:none` and change the first one after page load?

Comment: The samples used to exhibit the same loading problem until they were moved to hidden divs. Notice that the samples page hides all the wizards until a button is clicked.

Comment: Gary, I tried your suggestion. The issue is the first one doesn't show even after calling the jquery .show() method. However, if I advance to the next step and then click previous it does show. I can't figure out why it doesn't show on initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

To hide any particular step, I use this code:

```
$("#mySteps a[href='#mySteps-h-1']").hide();
```

Simply replace the numeric "1" with the index of any (or all) steps you wish to hide.  To show the step, just make a similar call:

```
$("#mySteps a[href='#mySteps-h-1']").show();
```